# How to print the length of \singlespacing and \doublespacing?

Tags: spacing

I am having some weird issues where the length of a single space is getting set to an undesirable value, somewhere, somehow, possibly.  It would be very helpful if I could print the lengths of a single space and double space.  However, `\the\singlespacing` doesn't work, because `\singlespacing` is a control not a variable.  How do I access the vertical spacing used by the `\singlespacing` command?

Comment: `\showthe\baselineskip` (for the terminal) or `\the\baselineskip` (to print it in document)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look in the package. From the command line

```latex
> latexdef -s -p setspace singlespacing onehalfspacing doublespacing
% setspace.sty, line 345:
\newcommand{\singlespacing}{%
  \setstretch {\setspace@singlespace}%  normally 1
  \vskip \baselineskip  % Correction for coming into singlespace
}

% setspace.sty, line 350:
\newcommand{\onehalfspacing}{%
  \setstretch{1.25}%  default
  \ifcase \@ptsize \relax % 10pt
    \setstretch {1.25}%
  \or % 11pt
    \setstretch {1.213}%
  \or % 12pt
    \setstretch {1.241}%
  \fi
}

% setspace.sty, line 361:
\newcommand{\doublespacing}{%
  \setstretch {1.667}%  default
  \ifcase \@ptsize \relax % 10pt
    \setstretch {1.667}%
  \or % 11pt
    \setstretch {1.618}%
  \or % 12pt
    \setstretch {1.655}%
  \fi
}
```

What's the definition of `\setstretch`?

```latex
> latexdef -s -p setspace setstretch
% setspace.sty, line 317:
\newcommand{\setstretch}[1]{%
  \def\baselinestretch{#1}%
  \@currsize
}
```

where `\@currsize` is essentially `\normalsize`.

You can get the current value of `\baselineskip` at a certain point in a document by doing

```latex
\the\baselineskip\ --- \ \baselinestretch
```

(better between paragraphs) and examining the output.